# Kentico 11 Portal Page Template - how to set Page AsyncMode?

Tags: kentico

I have a custom webpart that is inside a Portal Page template.  It needs to call an async web api method on a button click.

I know for an ASPX based template we would see the Page property like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ...... Async="true" %>
```

But I'm not sure if this is accessible using portal template.

If it's not possible and I have to create an ASPX template - is it possible for it to reference a portal based masterPage or would I have to pull that out into an aspx page too?

The reason I need this property set is support this code:

```
protected void btnProcessPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ExecuteValidation));
}

private async Task ExecuteValidation()
{
```

I have found this to be a reliable implementation in web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure that you can set a whole page as Async, there are other options here.

1. You could use Kentico's AsyncControl - this control is used throughout the admin interface for asynchronous processing
2. You could use Kentico's AsyncWorker - if for some reason you cannot
   use the AsyncControl this can be a valid alternative

Answer (score 0):

Async does not really stick well with whole webforms life cycle for controlls and callbacks can break the cycle, for example if a page is loaded. Running worker thread or AJAX calls are usually better option. Even AsyncControl is attaching to a thread at some point and leveraging it to do the job and changing its rendering based on that.

It could work as long as there are no other complex controls on the page. MVC will really help here, but that is beyond Kentico 11 and portal at this point.